# Ldap get users in a distribution list

Tags: java, ldap

I'm trying to get all the users of a DL using below code.The code is working as expected. However, I'm not able to get AD usernames for some users. Ex. First row of the o/p has username rkama but not the second row. Is this LDAP data issue or is there a different way to get user name/email address in a DL.

O/p
Entry is : CN=Ay\,Ram(rkama),OU=Site-SJN,OU=Accounts_User,DC=corp,DC=XXX,DC=com
Entry is : CN=Wang\,Peter(),OU=Site-SJN,OU=Accounts_User,DC=corp,DC=XXX,DC=com

```
public ArrayList<String> getAllDLs(String dlname) throws NamingException {
    ArrayList<String> dls = new ArrayList<String>();
    String attributes[] = { "member", "displayName" };
    createDLContext();
    SearchControls ctrl = new SearchControls();
    ctrl.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
    ctrl.setReturningAttributes(attributes);

    String search = "(&(objectClass=group)((sAMAccountName="+dlname+"*)))";
    NamingEnumeration enumeration = dlContext.search("", search, ctrl);

    while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
        SearchResult result = (SearchResult) enumeration.next();

        System.out.println("Found match & result is : " + result);
        NamingEnumeration<?> n2 = result.getAttributes().get("member").getAll(); 

        while (n2 != null && n2.hasMore()) {
            String dlList = (String) n2.next();
            System.out.println("Entry is : " + dlList);

        }
    }
    dlContext.close();      
    return dls;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to escape the `\` character. Have a look at http://www.rlmueller.net/CharactersEscaped.htm

Answer (score 0):

The `member` element only contains a `DN` for the user, this *is not* the username or password of the account, but a value that can be put back into the search to get the user information (including `cn` - the name of the user, and `sAMAccountName` - the userid of the user).

So you need to feed the `dlList` value into a second search (cleanly) e.g.

```
NamingEnumeration searchResult = dlContext.search("", "(dn={1})", new Object[]{ dlList }, ctrl);
```

Trying to construct the search with a simple string like `"(&(objectClass=group)((sAMAccountName="+dlname+"*)))"` will yield problems because the elements of the returned string will need to be escaped before putting it into the search (the `\` for example).